# Como ordenar dados no eixo Y usando ggplot2 em R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou plotando alguns dados em um gráfico Bubble Chart utilizando o pacote `ggplot2` do R.

Meus dados estão fora de ordem no eixo Y. Gostaria que seguissem a ordem dos números presentes nos nomes, por exemplo: `CenpSat1A`, `CenpSat2A`,  `CenaSat15Y`, porém não estou conseguindo quando só ordeno os dados.

Abaixo o código que usei para gerar o gráfico da imagem em anexo:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = Espécies, y = DNAsat, size = Reads, 
fill=Espécies)) + geom_point(shape = 21) + theme_bw() + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") + scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

`dput` para auxíliar a resposta:

```
structure(list(DNAsat = structure(c(9L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("CenaSat11B", 
"CenaSat12Y", "CenaSat15Y", "CenaSat2A", "CenaSat4A", "CenpSat10B", 
"CenpSat13Z", "CenpSat14Y", "CenpSat1A", "CenpSat3A", "CenpSat5Y", 
"CenpSat6A", "CenpSat7Y", "CenpSat8Z", "CenpSat9Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Espécies = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cenchrus americanus", 
    "Cenchrus purpureus"), class = "factor"), Reads = c(35629, 
    32123, 33698, 31857, 31812, 30664, 7534, 7128, 6395, 1887, 
    1865, 1435, 1069, 272, 18, 28201, 26867, 27799, 26206, 25967, 
    25987, 0, 11419, 0, 11879, 11887, 336, 0, 0, 220)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

[image: Gráfico Bubble_Chart]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pelas dicas. Inseri o resultado do dput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função fct_inorder do forcats do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) pode te ajudar

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

dados <- structure(list(DNAsat = structure(c(9L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 11L, 12L,  13L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 11L,  12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("CenaSat11B",  "CenaSat12Y", "CenaSat15Y", "CenaSat2A", "CenaSat4A", "CenpSat10B",  "CenpSat13Z", "CenpSat14Y", "CenpSat1A", "CenpSat3A", "CenpSat5Y",  "CenpSat6A", "CenpSat7Y", "CenpSat8Z", "CenpSat9Y"), class = "factor"),  Espécies = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cenchrus americanus",  "Cenchrus purpureus"), class = "factor"), Reads = c(35629,  32123, 33698, 31857, 31812, 30664, 7534, 7128, 6395, 1887,  1865, 1435, 1069, 272, 18, 28201, 26867, 27799, 26206, 25967,  25987, 0, 11419, 0, 11879, 11887, 336, 0, 0, 220)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -30L))


ggplot(dados,aes(x = Espécies, y = fct_rev(fct_inorder(DNAsat)), size = Reads, 
                  fill=Espécies)) + geom_point(shape = 21) + theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") + scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Obrigado pelo código. Carreguei o pacote forcats no R, porém quando rodo a linha de mutate tenho a seguinte resposta:


```Error in mutate(DNAsat = DNAsat %>% fct_inorder() %>% fct_rev()) : 
  não foi possível encontrar a função "mutate"```

Comment: a função mutate está no pacote dplyr, tenta instalar o tidyverse que já vem até mesmo o ggplot2 junto

Comment: Existe um meio de instalar o pacote externamente? Pois ele não está presente no banco do R Studio

Comment: Consegui instalar por comando.

Comment: e ai deu certo?

Comment: erro ao carregar o pacote:

```> library(tidyverse)
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required```

Comment: qual a sua versão do R, tenta instalar o rlang tb mas acho que não vai dar bom, se der tenta instalar só o dplyr vou mudar o código pra não precisar do dplyr mas vc deveria usar pq ele ajuda muito

Comment: vou atualizar a versão e ver se resolve.

Comment: Se precisar rápido coloquei uma versão sem o tidyverse, mas o código vai ficar mais confuso, esse call nested de fct_inorder e fct_rev é muito feio

Comment: Certo. Vou deixar salva e se a primeira versão não funcionar eu uso essa. Valeu mesmo cara.

Comment: Deu certo. Valeu mais uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra maneira de resolver esse problema é utilizando uma expressão regular para extrair apenas os números presentes em `DNAsat`. As vantagem desse método é evitar digitação em excesso, o que pode ocasionar erros.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

# extrair apenas os numeros presentes em DNAsat
numeros <- as.numeric(str_extract(dados$DNAsat, "[[:digit:]]+"))

ggplot(dados, aes(x = Espécies, y = reorder(DNAsat, -numeros), 
    size = Reads, fill=Espécies)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") + 
  scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, fica muito fácil inverter a ordem do gráfico, caso isso seja necessário:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = Espécies, y = reorder(DNAsat, numeros), 
    size = Reads, fill=Espécies)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") + 
  scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]